# Canon Multitasking printer: Scanner doesn't work, printer does

Tags: printing, scanner

Model: Canon Prixma MG2260

I have installed to ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr. Now I have the problem by my multi function device. The printer works, but the scanner doesn't!

I have downloaded the Linux software of Canon for the 2200 series. I have downloaded the software of the Internet site of Canon. 6 Zip folder 3 deb. and 3 rpm. Always 1 for computer, 1 for scanner, 1 for other Thinks. I can load them on my PC and unpacking, but they do not install themselves.

Does any person know what I have to do about this?

Comment: Could you please post a link to where you got the drivers?

Comment: Have you tried to install the `.deb` file via software-center? First unpacking then installing.

Comment: Have you tried downloading Simple Scan from the Ubuntu Software Centre?

Answer (score 0):

First check if the cable is working correctly!

Then check if the packages are available on Software center. if not then install them with package manager or dpkg (using Terminal) using these commands:

```
cd /path/to/packages/directory/
```

And then install them with dpkg:

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

and it will install all the packages ( i think you said 3).